# Pointer reference lost in dllexport

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllexport

I'm trying to call a CPP method from my C# code which returns me the below structure.

CPP:

```
struct ArrayD
{
int count;
float* arrayData;
}
```

C#:

```
struct ArrayD
{
int count;
IntPtr arrayData;
}
```

The array is initialized using std::make_unique in the CPP code and the struct is returned back.

But when i try to copy the IntPtr to a float array in C# using Marshal.Copy, I get Attempted to read/write corrupted memory error.

I confirmed that the reference to array is lost over the dll export, is there an way to keep the reference or data across the code.

Below is the code

```
extern "C" ArrayD _declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  CPPMetho()
    {
        auto arrayd  = std::make_unique<ArrayD>();
        arrayd.count = 10;

        auto arrayData = std::make_unique<float[]>(arrayd.count);

// Fill data to the array created above

        arrayd.arrayData= arrayData .get();

        return arrayd;
    }
```

I call the above API in my C# code, i get the value of "count" from the array, but when i try to Marshal the array data, i get exception.

Any idea how to keep the reference in C# to enable Marshalling

Comment: We can't see your C# code. But I don't think you can return a struct like that by value with pinvoke.

Comment: [DllImport(CPPDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern ArrayD CPPMetho();

and i Call this method inside my c# class. Even thought the struct was ceated inside the CPP method as unique ptr, im able to return it as val by dereferencing with the help if "*", but the array pointer inside that struct is lost

Comment: Return the struct as an out param. Stop trying to use C++ lifetime management.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are the problem:

```
auto arrayData = std::make_unique<float[]>(arrayd.count);

arrayd.arrayData= arrayData .get();
```

The first creates a smart pointer wrapping an array. The second line saves a pointer to the wrapped array.

Then when you return from the function, the life-time of `arrayData` ends and it is destructed, which then free's the array it wraps. Which leaves your saved pointer invalid, as it is now pointing to unallocated memory.

The solution is to either use smart pointers in the structure as well, or better yet use a `std::vector<float>` (in which case you don't need the structure at all).

Comment: I understood that and confirmed it. But i need to pass this data to C# , im not sure how smart pointer or vector will be marshalled in c#, any idea?

Comment: @BanusundarArumugam Considering that you are *already* returning a smart pointer (which is what `arrayd` is, being a `std::unique_ptr<ArrayD>` object), it's probably handled well by the marshalling. I think (but do not know) that marshalling a vector would work fine as well.

Comment: Sorry I'm not returning the smart pointer, the last line in the code is as below
return *arrayd. Let me try using vector. Thanks for the input

Comment: Returning C++ types like vector isn't going to pan out in interop.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal number of changes would be:

```
ArrayD arrayd = {};
arrayd.count = 10;

// std::unique_ptr<float[]> arrayData
// don't let auto hide what the types really are!
auto arrayData = std::make_unique<float[]>(arrayd.count);

// Fill data to the array created above

arrayd.arrayData = arrayData.release();
return arrayd;
```

Note that I've changed the allocation of `arrayd`. Now it is a stack variable. And for the `arrayData` I've added a `release()` so that the `std::unique_ptr<>` created by `std::make_unique<float[]>` won't release it. You'll have to create a companion `FreeArrayD(ArrayD& arrayData)` to free the allocated memory.